# Android webview local file setting root

Tags: javascript, android, webview, android-webview

I am loading a local web application using a webview in Android:

```
view.loadUrl("https://appassets.androidplatform.net/assets/dist/index.html")
```

However when I check the current route in my JavaScript it says `https://appassets.androidplatform.net/assets/dist/index.html`

This makes stuff like routing and file loading kind of a pain - is there a way to set the root of the loaded application, so I can avoid the whole `/assets/` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [WebViewAssetLoader](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/webkit/WebViewAssetLoader) the code snippet there does exactly what you need. So you basically just need to forward all the requests which can be handled by the assetsLoader to it, and use the response that it returns.

```
final WebViewAssetLoader assetLoader = new WebViewAssetLoader.Builder()
          .addPathHandler("/assets/", new AssetsPathHandler(this))
          .build();

 webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
     @Override
     @RequiresApi(21)
     public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view,
                                      WebResourceRequest request) {
         return assetLoader.shouldInterceptRequest(request.getUrl());
     }

     @Override
     @SuppressWarnings("deprecation") // for API < 21
     public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view,
                                      WebResourceRequest request) {
         return assetLoader.shouldInterceptRequest(Uri.parse(request));
     }
 });

 WebSettings webViewSettings = webView.getSettings();
 // Setting this off for security. Off by default for SDK versions >= 16.
 webViewSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(false);
 // Off by default, deprecated for SDK versions >= 30.
 webViewSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(false);
 // Keeping these off is less critical but still a good idea, especially if your app is not
 // using file:// or content:// URLs.
 webViewSettings.setAllowFileAccess(false);
 webViewSettings.setAllowContentAccess(false);

 // Assets are hosted under http(s)://appassets.androidplatform.net/assets/... .
 // If the application's assets are in the "main/assets" folder this will read the file
 // from "main/assets/www/index.html" and load it as if it were hosted on:
 // https://appassets.androidplatform.net/assets/www/index.html
 webview.loadUrl("https://appassets.androidplatform.net/assets/www/index.html");
```

Comment: could you give me a code example of this i feel like ive tried that aswell but without success?

Comment: Basically the code is the page I've linked should be enough, you don't need to do any further changes, I've added the sample code in the solution, give it a try

Comment: when running window.location.href it will say https://appassets.androidplatform.net/assets/www/index.html

my question is if it is possible to host this at the root of the directory

Comment: I didn't really get what you're aiming to achieve, how is your site structured? Is it completely local and embedded in app's assets?

Comment: yes that is correct

Comment: Well in this case you don't really need to care about what base url your site is referring, if you use relative links in your site, and tell the webview to consider the assetsloader